# Django uniqe by date queryset filtering

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I have a queryset which represent visits and now I need to filter unique visits by day for all week.

```
class Visit(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


week = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=7)
visits = Visit.objects.filter(created_at__gte=week)
```

How can I filter visits queryset to get unique visits per day for one week range. So if user comes 4 times in a single day, it is one unique visit. Expected result is integer which represent unique visits for the last week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below will create a new field in the queryset called `visit_date`: that is the date (stripped of the time) from the `created_at` attribute of your model. Using the `Count` function, we can then group the queryset by the user and date, and count the number of visits for each date:

```
from django.db.models import Count

week = timezone.now().date() - timedelta(days=7)
visits = Visit.objects.filter(created_at__gte=week)).extra({'visit_date' : 'date(created_at)'}).values('user', 'visit_date').annotate(visits_on_date=Count('pk'))
```

The `visits` queryset will looks something along the lines of:

```
[
    {'user': 1, 'visit_date': datetime.date(2016, 11, 4), 'visits_on_date': 2},
    {'user': 2, 'visit_date': datetime.date(2016, 11, 4), 'visits_on_date': 5},
    {'user': 1, 'visit_date': datetime.date(2016, 11, 3), 'visits_on_date': 7},
    {'user': 2, 'visit_date': datetime.date(2016, 11, 3), 'visits_on_date': 9},
    {'user': 1, 'visit_date': datetime.date(2016, 11, 2), 'visits_on_date': 5}
]
```

Each item in the queryset relates to a unique visit for that date for a particular user. You can determine the number of unique visits by:

```
visits.count()
```

Which in this instance would be 5.

You can also use this to determine the number of visits a particular user makes, by looking at the `visits_on_date` field in the queryset.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.

Comment: I had trouble getting this answer to truncate the datetime down to a date, and thus was not able to get it to filter distinct dates. 

If you're looking to get the number of distinct days, weeks or months that exist on a datetimefield from objects in a queryset, you may want to look at dates() 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#dates